# My qhttp get() call does not work on Windows but does on Linux

Tags: c++, qt, get

I have written a program that uses qhttp to get a webpage. This works fine on Linux, but does not work on my Windows box (Vista). It appears that the qhttp done signal is never received.

The relevant code is:

```
    Window::Window()
{
    http = new QHttp(this);
    connect(http, SIGNAL(done(bool)), this, SLOT(httpDone(bool)));
url = new QUrl("http://something.com/status.xml");
http->setHost(url->host(), url->port() != -1 ? url->port() : 80);
    if (!url->userName().isEmpty()) http->setUser(url->userName(), url->password());
}

void Window::retrievePage()
{ 
byteArray = new QByteArray;
result = new QBuffer(byteArray);
result->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    httpRequestAborted = false;
    httpGetId = http->get(url->path(), result);
 }

 void Window::httpDone(bool error)
 {
     //Never gets here!
 }
```

Any help would be appriecated.

Matt

Comment: Can you make sure this isn't one of those UAC issues? Try to turn off UAC and let us know if you are seeing any security popups.

Comment: Thanks. I have now tried that and it stills does not work. I have since tried it on an XP machine and get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not happen at all, i.e. QHttp works reliably both on Windows and Unix.

My advice is to check whether the serves gives proper response. This can be done e.g. by verifying that data transfer is fine. You can trace the status from QHttp's signal, e.g. [dataReadProgress](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qhttp.html#dataReadProgress), [requestStarted](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qhttp.html#requestStarted), [requestFinished](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qhttp.html#requestFinished),  and other related signals.

On the other hand, instead of using old QHttp, why not using the recommended [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) instead? To get your feet wet quickly, check an example I posted to Qt Labs some time ago: [image viewer with remote URL drag-and-drop support](http://labs.trolltech.com/blogs/2008/11/08/image-viewer-with-remote-url-drag-and-drop-support/). It uses the said [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) to grab the image from the dropped URL. Check the [source-code](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt-labs/graphics-dojo/blobs/master/dragremote/dragremote.cpp), it is only 150 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten as suggested by Ariya to use QNetworkAccessManager and looking at [this example](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001431_-_Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt)

This now works on Windows and Linux.

```
Window::Window()
{
   connect(&manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(retrieveData(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void Window::retrieveMessage()
{
    manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://...")));
}

void Window::retrieveData(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    QVariant statusCodeV = 
    reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    // "200 OK" received?
    if (statusCodeV.toInt()==200)
    {
        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
    }

    reply->deleteLater();
}
```